# file upload path dynamic issue

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I need to upload file .
I get a value as dynamic value
Im using angular js also.

```
$reg =  "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('regNo'));</script>";
```

Am getting correct value for $reg.

```
$uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'Folder1/folder2/'. $reg. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
```

But by using this, my file is not getting uploaded.

But if I use the below code (If $reg = img1),  it will be a success.

```
$uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'Folder1/folder2/img1'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
```

What is the difference . PLease help me beacuse $reg is a dynamic value.

Comment: Just to make sure, you do know that this: `$reg =  "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('regNo'));</script>";` won't give you the value of the local storage item, right? It will just store the literal string `"<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('regNo'));</script>"` in the variable `$reg`. PHP can't run JS.

Comment: so how can I solve the issue? any idea.

Comment: You need to use Ajax to call the value from JS to a PHP-file.

Comment: but if i echo $reg , am getting correct value.

Comment: thanks for your valuable point... @ Magnus Eriksson